# Which WebCL prototype should I use?

Tags: web, opencl, gpgpu

I'm thinking of doing some experiments on WebCL. I'm good in OpenCL/CUDA on GPUs. How different is the experience in general and which implementation should I use? [Samsung](http://code.google.com/p/webcl/) or [Nokia](http://webcl.nokiaresearch.com/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is  a  third WebCL   prototype
https://github.com/Motorola-Mobility/node-webcl

I had to down rev my browser to run  the Nokia WebCL.   But I was able write some complex  examples.  The issue I see if the time taken to  initialize  a GPU ~45 ms and the time taken to compile a kernel ~145ms. In ~200 ms I can do ~2M FLOPS in Javscript, So when does WebCL gain over JS ...

Comment: Oh I didn't know there was another one!!. Yeah, you are right about the gain. It's only useful when there is a lot of data-parallel stuff to process. I had social network analysis in mind.

Comment: Anyways, I installed Nokia and it crashes every time I run something. I'm definitely switching to other implementations.

Answer (score 0):

You can find plenty of updated examples for Nokia's prototype:
https://github.com/jmietola/webcl-firefox-examples

Also Nokia's prototype is up-to-date. So current version works with FireFox25.